# Two tags for anaesthesia

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tags [anaesthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaesthesia) and [anesthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anesthesia). Shouldn't they be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged them and made them synonyms.